# Charset GBK JSON

Tags: php, python, json

I tried extracting charset of gbk and transferred it to my server, waiting to be stored in DB then extracted displayed as gbk but i'm getting weird text
Code is in Python

```
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json;charset=gbk'}
        r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)  
        print(r.text)
```

I get text like éçº¢è²#104#é»è²#103#S-2013ç§å¬åçº§

Is there any solution to this? Do i have to store it and display it then set my page's charset to gbk. Will that work?

PHP Code

```
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
```

Comment: Try `print(r.content.decode('gbk'))`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the response does not contain encoding information or have invalid information.

Check `r.encoding`.

Try decode the content first.

```
print(r.content.decode('gbk'))
```

If that does not work try following workaround (Python 3.3):

```
>>> text = 'éçº¢è²#104#é»è²#103#S-2013ç§å¬åçº§'
>>> text.encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
'酒红色#104#黑色#103#S-2013秋冬升级'
```

Comment: Okay, testing it now, just curious, can i just store and decode only when i'm retrieving it from database? or can i store a gbk?

Comment: Because the main purpose is to display on php not python

Comment: @RainbowHat, Sorry, I don't understand your comment question. And I'm not good at PHP.